# How to install synapse in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, lxde

I got `lxde`, and I am very new to it.I found out there were no search tool for it

I went online and found it and I did

```
sudo apt-get install synapse
```

it did not  work.It says

```
Unable to locate package synapse
```

I realy want a search tool, so I can access my folder,my games on steam and minecraft (.minecraft folder)

I tried the other name too.. semantic launcher (didn't work), can someone tell me wants wrong or.. help me install another search tool?

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not want to work"? Can you share the terminal output? ALso I'm afraid there is no synapse package in Ubuntu official repositories so you are on your own try to search a thir party repository in Launchpad.

Comment: *xangua heres the output:*                                               'Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package synapse'

Comment: @SirCarster: Run `sudo apt-get update` and then try the installation command.

Comment: Actually http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/synapse exists and is a "semantic file launcher"; however this is for precise (12.04LTS). I dont see this was ported to 14.04. Also I don't know what exactly is needed from "search tool" -- to search something in local drives?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<s>`synapse` is not available for Ubuntu 14.04 .</s> But you can install it by adding [Synapse core team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~synapse-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

To install `synapse` in Ubuntu 14.04, open terminal and type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:synapse-core/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synapse
```

It should install `synapse` in your system.

---

#### EDIT

`synapse` is now available in Ubuntu Universe repository ([See here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=synapse)).
To install it you need to  enable the  universe repository . 
Enable it using

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
```

and then install `synapse` using

```
sudo apt-get install synapse
```

**However above PPA can be used to get the latest version of `synapse`**

Comment: can this be updated for 16.04?

Comment: @hakermania, It will work on 16.04 as well.

Comment: `E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/synapse-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found` but it is evidently available in `universe`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` did you run this command @Hatshepsut

Answer (score 4):

`sudo apt install synapse` works out of the box for Ubuntu 18.04 for anyone wondering