# Can't access settings on fresh install synapse for kUbuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: kubuntu, 16.04, synapse

I have been using instructions that can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577711/how-to-install-synapse-in-ubuntu-14-04) for my 14.04 systems. But after running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:synapse-core/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following on kUbuntu 16.04LTS:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/synapse-core/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/synapse-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/synapse-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

If I proceed to install, it will install but not function properly (can't access settings). In kUbuntu 14LTS I would left click the icon in the system tray to change settings. In kUbuntu 16LTS I can right click all the other icons and change settings but not the icon for synapse.

Am I installing synapse wrong in kUbuntu 16LTS? How do I access the settings?

System notes:
kUbuntu 16.04LTS in Vmware

Answer (score 2):

Synapse has been added to  the official software repository for (K)Ubuntu 16.04, so you shouldn't need to bother with a PPA. You can remove the PPA and install Synapse from the official repositories by running the following commands, one at a time:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:synapse-core/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install synapse
```

Please let me know if you run into problems, or how this worked for you.

Comment: This made it clear the problem I was having isn't related to the output after inappropriately adding the ppa. There is an issue with synapse itself in new kUbuntu 16LTS preventing me from accessing settings. I've tried 2 fresh installs. so I need to rephrase the question.