# Synapse website no longer exists?

Tags: synapse

I'm considering using Synapse app launcher and was looking for the website, but I can't find it.

The website mentioned everywhere is synapse.zeitgeist-project.com, but it doesn't seem to exist?

Is the project dead? Is zeitgeist dead?

Comment: This? https://www.synapse.org/

Comment: No. Synapse the zeigeist based app launcher

Comment: Ah. Why not use PPAs? http://askubuntu.com/questions/577711/how-to-install-synapse-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I can install it find. I wanted the website for things like seeing what extensions where available, seeing if there where docs/apis, and just general looking around.

Comment: Activity on the Launchpad page suggests the project isn't dead (https://launchpad.net/synapse-project). Since the domain refuses to connect and doesn't say there are no DNS records, I think they're just having issues.

Answer (score 1):

The project is alive alright.

https://launchpad.net/synapse-project

```
sudo apt install synapse
```

tested in 18.04.